# Manjaro: Change default text editor to Sublime Text 3

Tags: editors, manjaro

I recently installed Manjaro Linux. I love everything so far, but I have been having some issues with my favorite text editor, Sublime Text 3. I installed it from Octopi, but I can't run it from the terminal. Running `apropos` with various keywords turns up nothing. Furthermore, I can't figure out a way to change the default text editor to Sublime Text 3. If I right click on an application and click `Open With...` then click set as default, it will only select Sublime Text as the default for that specific file, i.e. `.c` source files, but not `.py` files. I use a lot of different extensions on a regular basis and I do not want to have to do that again if I reinstall Manjaro. Does anyone know a way to run ST3 from a terminal in Manjaro and set it as the default text editor?

Frankly, I am lost with this, so if there is any info you need, just request it in the comments and I will edit the question to include it.

Thanks very much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that I am writing with a major delay but today I was also trying to change the default text editor. My Manjaro was using Kate by default and the way I managed to change it globally was:

1. Find out where your Sublime text is installed, usually it's binary is called "subl", you can find out the location by using:

   $: which subl
2. Navigate to a .txt file

   Right Click -> Open With -> Other
3. You'll see a new window with a input field at the top. Enter the path to your subl binary there, in my case it was

   /usr/bin/subl
4. At the bottom check the tick for "Remember application association for all files of plain text document (text/plain)"

This should do it, I've also attached a screenshot of the setup here:
[image: manjaro-default-app]